# How can I index .JSON in elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am starting with `elasticsearch` now and i don't know anything about it.
I have folowing `.JSON`:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Admin Law",
    "tags": [
      "#admin"
    ],
    "owner": "generalTopicTagText"
  },
  {
    "label": "Judicial review",
    "tags": [
      "#JR"
    ],
    "owner": "generalTopicTagText"
  },
  {
    "label": "Admiralty/Shipping",
    "tags": [
      "#shipping"
    ],
    "owner": "generalTopicTagText"
  }
]
```

My `mapping` is this:

```
{
  "topic_tax": {
    "properties": {
      "label": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "string",
        "index_name": "tag"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to put the first .Json into `Elasticsearch`, but it does not work.

All I know is that i am defining only 1 of this:

```
{
  "label": "Judicial review",
  "tags": [
    "#JR"
  ],
  "owner": "generalTopicTagText"
}
```

So when i try to put all of them with my `elasticsearch.init`, it will not work.

But I really don't know how to declare the `mapping.Json` to put the all .Json, it is like i need something like a for there.

Comment: You need to insert them as seperate documents.

Comment: really? it is the only way?  i have like 600 docs in that case.. @EvaldasBuinauskas

Comment: Really. there's no other way. I'd suggest making a simple app, that would split this into seperate objects and bulk insert them. Shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: ok i will try it, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert them json after json. But what you should do is use the bulk api of elasticsearch to insert multiple documents in one request. Check this [api doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to see how it works

Comment: i am trying to make a javascript function to read the .Json and after that call to the index function of elasticsearch

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like this

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9000/es/post/1?version=2' -d '{
    "text" : "your test message!"
}'
```

here is the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) for index json with elasticsearch

Comment: Links only answers are not very helpful. Try to provide some context just in case the link you provide goes away or is unavailable.